# Accessing "0" inside SimpleXMLObject in PHP

Tags: php

I am running some queries against an API that will return an XML string, which I then convert to a SimpleXMLObject in PHP. The problem I am having is I can't access certain values. I will have a very strange structure that won't let me access the values I need. Here is an example of the output of one of the objects.

```
[totalCostOfFees] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                    )
```

How would I get the value of that? I have one that is...

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($var);
echo "</pre>";

<pre>Array
(
[26105] => Array
    (
        [rate request] => Array
            (
                [success] => 1
                [cost] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => 30
                    )
                ...
```

I can get to the "cost" section, but I am always left with array(0 => 30);
I need the value, not the array. Obviously I can't use

```
$variable[$id]['cost']->0; // that will fail for obvious reasons
```

and I have tried..

```
$variable[$id]['cost'][0];
```

But that gives me an empty array.
Please help, it is driving me nuts. Thank you.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Could you please at least link me to the post you are saying this is a duplicate of, I couldn't find one that answered this question. Thank you

Comment: It's at the top of your question.  The accepted answer should work for you.